# Can't get port 23 open on CentOS 6.8

Tags: centos, iptables

I have just upgraded from CentOS 6.6 to 6.8 (64bit).  We have a site-licensed telnet client that allows multiple windows on a single database seat. I have disabled SELinux and rebooted the system.

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#   enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#   permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#   disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#   targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#   strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
[root@localhost selinux]#
```

I have disabled the firewall.  This is the telnet file in the xinetd.d directory.

```
#
{
    disable = no
  bind         = 10.99.0.6
  flags        = REUSE
  wait         = no
  socket_type  = stream
  only_from    = 10.99.0.0
  user         = root
#  server       = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
  server       = /usr/uv/bin/uvtelnetd
  log_on_failure += USERID
}
```

This is the iptables file:

```
[root@localhost etc]# more /etc/sysconfig/iptables# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Mon Mar 27 13:33:58 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [40:5382]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:131]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2:131]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Mar 27 13:33:58 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Mon Mar 27 13:33:58 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [29:2732]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i em1 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i em1 -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Mar 27 13:33:58 2017
```

If I do `lsof`, this is what I see.

```
[root@localhost etc]# lsof -i | grep 23
cupsd      2080    root    6u  IPv6  12381      0t0  TCP localhost6.localdomain6:ipp (LISTEN)
cupsd      2080    root    7u  IPv4  12382      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:ipp (LISTEN)
cupsd      2080    root    9u  IPv4  12385      0t0  UDP *:ipp 
rpc.mount  2281    root   11u  IPv4  13232      0t0  UDP *:57448 
rpc.mount  2281    root   12u  IPv4  13236      0t0  TCP *:42105 (LISTEN)
pluto      2623    root   22u  IPv4  13994      0t0  UDP 10.99.0.6:isakmp 
pluto      2623    root   23u  IPv4  13995      0t0  UDP 10.99.0.6:ipsec-nat-t 
pluto      2623    root   24u  IPv4  13996      0t0  UDP localhost.localdomain:isakmp 
pluto      2623    root   25u  IPv4  13997      0t0  UDP localhost.localdomain:ipsec-nat-t 
pluto      2623    root   26u  IPv6  13998      0t0  UDP localhost6.localdomain6:isakmp
```

I still get a "connection refused" even if I try the telnet from the server console.

As a beginner on iptables and xinetd I'm not sure what I have done wrong. How can I make this work?

I followed Moonpoint's suggestions:

```
[root@localhost ~]# service xinetd restart
Stopping xinetd:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting xinetd:                                           [  OK  ]
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -an | grep 23
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18013  /tmp/orbit- root/linc-e3b-0-12ce87623f7f2
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12383  /var/run/cups/cups.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12340  /var/lib/samba/winbindd_privileged/pipe
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12337  /var/run/winbindd/pipe
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20234  @/tmp/dbus-1a1aDNA0S2
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20233  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     19723  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     19239  @/tmp/dbus-1a1aDNA0S2
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     19238  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18323  @/dbus-vfs-daemon/socket-9ID2XSeB
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18232  @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18231  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18016  /tmp/orbit-root/linc-e3b-0-12ce87623f7f2
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17223  /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14323  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12343  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12342  
[root@localhost ~]# 


xinetd          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
ypbind          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off

xinetd based services:
chargen-dgram:  off
chargen-stream: off
daytime-dgram:  off
daytime-stream: off
discard-dgram:  off
discard-stream: off
echo-dgram:     off
echo-stream:    off
rsync:          on
tcpmux-server:  on
telnet:         on
time-dgram:     off
time-stream:    off
[root@localhost ~]# telnet 10.99.0.6
Trying 10.99.0.6...
telnet: connect to address 10.99.0.6: Connection refused
[root@localhost ~]# telnet localhost
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
[root@localhost ~]#
```

So even though chkconfig thinks telnet is running, something is still in the way.

Dale

Comment: By the way the commented lines just show as bold, an effect of the "#" somewhere along the way.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I've fixed your formatting for you - for help in formatting your posts, see [this help center article](https://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

There's no evidence in the information you provided that the telnet server software is listening for connections on port 23. Try issuing the command `service xinetd restart` then check to see if the system is listening on port 23 with `netstat -an | grep 23`. If you then see the system is listening on port 23, then from the system itself try `telnet 10.99.0.6`, since that is the IP address it is configured to listen on, i.e., it isn't configured to listen on all IP addresses on that system, just that particular one, because that is the IP address to which it is bound.

To ensure the telnet [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) will listen on that port for connections after a reboot, issue the commands below:

```
chkconfig telnet on
chkconfig xinetd on
```

I'm not sure how the comment "We have a site-licensed telnet client that allows multiple windows on a single database seat" relates to your efforts to enable the telnet server software, though. I.e., if your problem is with getting the system to function as a telnet server, I'm unsure why you mentioned the site-licensed telnet client.

Comment: This telnet client allows a user to open 10 sessions for the price of 1 seat.  SSH is working but 2 sessions would take 2 seats.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was so far down the chain of "try this" hacks that I couldn't deconstruct it.  I think that though "chkconfig" thought telnet was running, it wasn't.  Ultimately I re-installed the Centos 6.8, immediately yum'ed telnet-server telnet and the samba modules.  Problem solved, thanks for your help.